# Where can I find logical fallacies in action?

Tags: logic, reference-request, fallacies

I'm looking for a website that gives logical fallacies in action.

Not a video that explains logical fallacies, but a video, say a debate between two people where one of the debators uses a logical fallacy.

Specifically I'm looking for the law of excluded middle. I've watched multiple YouTube videos explaining what the law is. I would like to see a video where this specific law (and others) are being used by a specific person.

Comment: Does it mean that you take the law of excluded middle to be fallacious?

Comment: @Conifold It can be: for example, creationists often attack this small issue of that in evolutionary theory, with the hidden premise that the middle is excluded, and any successful argument against some aspect of evolution is a successful argument *for* creationism. This is a deliberate strategy, because it is much more difficult (!) to make positive *scientific* arguments for creationism directly.

Comment: An example: Two groups are arguing whether an action should be taken or not. One group argues that the action will have bad consequences, the other group argues that the action will have positive consequence, both sides with made-up arguments and very little actual evidence. Now one side argues that the first group argues with fear, and the second argues with hope, and we should choose hope instead of fear. Any similarities with real events are not coincidental, but unavoidable.

Comment: @Dan This sounds like a false dilemma to me rather than excluded middle, evolution, let alone on specifics, and creationism are not negations of each other https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma Intuitionists believe that even LEM proper still fails on their elpistemology. But they know that most reject it, so they normally wouldn't call LEM a "fallacy" since that would beg the question.

Comment: Examine any metaphysical problem in academic philosophy and you'll find a misuse of the LEM. The crucial mistake is setting up faux-contradictions in the form of A/not-A while ignoring Aristotle's rule for contradictory pairs. It's such a common mistake in scholastic philosophy you'll have trouble avoiding good examples. . .

Comment: How about just watch a political speech or debate?

Comment: I don't think asking for links to volatile online resources is on-topic in this Stackexchange. How could something be a correct answer?

Comment: You could make this a practical exercise by going to the front page of any major newspaper and finding the logical fallacies in the reporting and in what is being reported. Take any politician's plan to build this or fund that and take apart the logic. Or we have to invade this or that country. Look at how life or death foreign policy decisions are made. The world runs on logical fallacies. Start looking in your everyday life for examples of where people rationalize illogical actions. It's hard to miss logical fallacies in action. They're everywhere.

Comment: Was there a specific situation that brought this question to mind? Examples of fallacious arguments are actually hard to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Bo Bennett's site *Logically Fallacious* provides dialogues for arguments that Bennett considers to be legitimate fallacies and not pseudo-fallacies.

Here are two examples he provides for the *[Ad Hominem](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/1/Ad_Hominem_Abusive)* logical fallacy:

> My opponent suggests that lowering taxes will be a good idea -- this is coming from a woman who eats a pint of Ben and Jerry’s each night!
>
> Tony wants us to believe that the origin of life was an “accident”.  Tony is a godless SOB who has spent more time in jail than in church, so the only information we should consider from him is the best way to make license plates.

Explanations are provided for the examples. Where appropriate exceptions and tips are also offered for these examples.

For the law of excluded middle see *[False Dilemma](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/94/False-Dilemma)*.

---

Bennett, B. "Ad Hominem (Abusive)" Retrieved on May 12, 2019 from *Logically Fallacious* at https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/1/Ad_Hominem_Abusive